# 6 pin PSU and 4 pin motherboard

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

recently purchased a new gigabtye 970a motherboard. The only issue I have is that while the atx 12v port on the mobo is 4 pin, the PSU cable seems to be 6 pin. Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: We need more information about the power supply.

Comment: I'm afraid I can find nothing on it to tell me much, only it's a 650W supply installed in 2011... I'll try to find more..

Comment: Something's not right here. The 970a doesn't have a 4-pin connector on it. 8-pin yes, but 4-pin no.

Comment: 6-pin is for graphics. 4 or 8 pin is for the mobo - sometimes the plug is splittable into 2x4; only the correct half will fit, whether it splits or not.

Comment: ah, I read it the wrong way round - so new mobo, old PSU; will have to update the PSU to fit

Comment: I should have specified the motherboard more clearly; it's this revision of the 970a, which has a 4pin atx-12V connection. http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4642#ov

Comment: @DRG following your link, the specifications say *1 x 8-pin ATX 12V power connector* and the photo confirms it.

Comment: @DRG If your power supply provides molex connectors you could use a molex-to-8pin 12v ATX adapter (http://tinyurl.com/ky6pxa8). Only do this is you are *absolutely sure* the power supply can actually supply enough juice through the molex connector and whatever else is connected to the same rail. Depends how the rails are distributed. If you're not sure what I'm talking about don't risk it and just get a new beefy power supply with the right connectors and follow the instructions :-)

Answer (score 0):

took some of your advice and looked around the forums for similar problems; sure enough buried in my case was an 8 pin power supply which readily split intot 2 x 4 pin supplies.

I connected this up and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the pointers here. Moral of the story is to keep your cables well order; I missed the 8 pin plug as it was originally hidden behind a different lead. Have clipped everything back now and all is good!